# Regular Expression matching a phrase and everything up to but not including the next match?

Tags: regex, python-re

I've been trying to use regular expression to simplify a text parser for my job.
But I am running into issues when trying to capture two matches in the same line.

The match I am trying to capture would look something like this when read in Python.

```
> 12.1 Text I need to capture24.11.51 Text I need to capture
```

I have been using the pattern `'\d{1,2}[.]\d{1,2}([.]\d{1,2})? \D(.*)'` to match with just the numbers and capture everything after it per line, but I am stumped on how to avoid capturing the second.

I have seen on other answers, they are always matching the same phrase multiple times, I am not sure how you would do it when the phrase to match is not an exact copy.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: E.g. `re.findall(r'(?s)(?<!\d)\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\b.*?(?=(?<!\d)\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\b|\Z)', text)` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/TLYO8S/1)) or `re.findall(r'(?<!\d)\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\b(?:(?!(?<!\d)\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}).)*', text)`